# useState não atualiza - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, array, node.js, react

Estou iniciando no mundo do ReactJS. Tenho um front que está consumindo uma API de rastreamento, para isso ele me retorna um objeto com status, responseMessage e object, um array de objetos. Faço a desestruturação da requisição e ele realiza o print normalmente no console. Porém no momento em que tento alterar o estado, ele não acusa nenhum erro mas também não altera o estado do componente.

```
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [dados, setDados] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function loadData(){
      await dispatch(signInRequestMultiportal());
      const response = await apiMultiportal.request({
        url: 'posicoes/ultimaPosicao',
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          token: store.getState().auth.tokenMultiportal,
        }
      });

      const { object } = response.data;
      console.log(object)
      setDados(object);
      console.log(dados);
    }
    loadData();
  }, [])
```

```
{
 "status": 'OK',
 "responseMessage": "Requisição concluida",
 "object": [{
 }]
}
```

Print do objeto, o de cima é o `console.log(object)` o de baixo o `console.log(dados)`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: se está falando que não altera também na tela ou so no console.log? `console.log(dados);`?:

Comment: No console.log aparece os dados, mas no useState não

Comment: seu object ta vindo nada, tipo um array com 0 posições! se viu isso?

Comment: No `console.log(object)` aparece todos os dados, porém no `console.log(dados)` simplesmente aparece um [  ]

Comment: se está confundindo as bolas, o console.log(data) não tem dados ainda levo um tempo para atualizar seguinte segue o exemplo abaixo que vou criar

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!

Comment: se deu certo assinale como resposta do sua pergunta

Answer (score 4):

A variável de estado precisa ser monitorada para que tenha as suas alterações e isso é fácilmente resolvido com a utilização de `useEffect` com um paramento de `array` contendo a sua variável a ser monitorada, um exemplo simples:

```js
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);

  const loadData = () => {
    let item = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      item.push(i);
    }
    setData(item);
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    loadData();
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => { // esse é responsável em pegar as alterações
    console.log(data);
  }, [data]); // pela configuração no `array` com o nome da variável

  return (
    <div>      
      <ul>
      {data.map((i,k) => (<li>{i}</li>))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

do jeito que você fez como a alteração não é percebida porque é assíncrona e por isso o uso o `useEffect` é necessário

Answer (score 1):

Lucas, o useEffects é bem interessante, porém, se você não colocar nada no array do segundo argumento, ele vai executar uma única vez, colocando uma propriedade ali, ela vai executar toda vez que tiver uma alteração naquela variável.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [dados, setDados] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function loadData(){
      await dispatch(signInRequestMultiportal());
      const response = await apiMultiportal.request({
        url: 'posicoes/ultimaPosicao',
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          token: store.getState().auth.tokenMultiportal,
        }
      });

      const { object } = response.data;
      console.log(object)
      setDados(object);
      console.log(dados);
    }
    loadData();
  }, [dados]) // Apenas colocar a propriedade para ficar sendo observada
```

Fiz um exemplo no JSFiddle para melhor exemplificar caso ainda tenha ficado dúvida.

https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielgstein/4hwvo0Lj/3/

Answer (score 1):

O que está acontecendo nesse caso é que quando useEffect é executado o valor de estado da variavel data é o valor inicial, se você adicionar a variavel `data` no array de dependencias o codigo vai executar como você espera.

`React.useEffect(function loadData(){....}, [data])`

porém a função loadData() sera executada duas vezes o que não é ideal.
então você pode separar os `console.log()` em outro useEffect()

`React.useEffect(()=>{console.log(data)}, [data])`